# TypeError while flattening list of lists of string type

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I have a dataset which goes as follows:

ds = [['North','Raw','Tree'],['Saw','Raw','Apple'],['Saw','Apple'],['Gum','Saw'],......]

The dataset has 211945 values. I have imported this dataset in Jupyter and tried running the below code for making this list of lists as a single list.

Code:

```
     list_1 = []
     for sublist in ds:
       for val in sublist:
           list_1.append(val)
```

The error I got was:

```
  1 list_1 = []
  2 for sublist in ds:
  3     for val in sublist: <---
  4         list_1.append(val)
```

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

The expected output is:

list_1 = ['North','Raw','Tree','Saw','Raw','Apple','Saw','Apple','Gum','Saw',......]

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. Maybe your dataset cause the error

Comment: It should be work as far as you have sub list in your list. From error It seems you may have `float` value in your list put your original list in question.

Comment: Please check your minimal example first, then re post it again with the problem. You seem to have some kind of scoping problem.

Comment: This error cannot be reproduced with the code you have shown. Please make sure that `ds` has the value you expect it to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.chain https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html. This is perferct for your case, I think.

```
import itertools


ds = [['N','R','T'],['S','R','A'],['S','A']]

print(list(itertools.chain(*ds)))
```

Comment: I have tried this method and it didn't work. It showed the same error

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.chain()` is very common idiom for this, but if you prefer list comprehensions, it can be done with the one liner

`flattened = [j for i in lsts for j in i]`

which is maybe easier to read.

Comment: Just to ensure I didn't make any typos I tried it with the literal input in the question, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list =[]
for x in ds:
   try:
      new_list.extend(x)
   except:
      new_list.extend([x])
```

I feel your lists might have some elements that aren't list. For example 'ds' might be like either [['a','b'],['c','d'],'e',['f','g']....] i.e a mixture of lists & single_elements. The above code should work as this will consider each singular element as a list in the 'except' case as & when an error occurs in 'try' case